# CSS vertical to horizontal flow chart

Tags: html, list, css, flowchart

I have been playing around with this pen but am at a loss of how to make this horizontal and not vertical so the parent would be first centered vertical and then the children would come off to the right instead of from top down.

http://codepen.io/abennington/pen/MajVxa

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.tree {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  width: auto !important;
}
.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.tree li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  white-space: normal;
  display: inline-block;
}
/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
    any siblings*/

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}
/*Remove space from the top of single children*/

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}
/*Remove left connector from first child and 
    right connector from last child*/

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}
.tree li a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
/*Time for some hover effects*/

/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/

.tree li a:hover,
.tree li a:hover+ul li a {
  background: #c8e4f8;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/

.tree li a:hover+ul li::after,
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before {
  border-color: #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Parent</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It is already flowing vertically, maybe you want to make it horizontal instead?

Comment: And where is the code of your attempt.? It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Yeah sorry it should be horizontal.

Comment: The code i tried is so busted it would not make sense what i was trying to do. I have searched all over but no help from Google.

Comment: you can check this out for reference http://codepen.io/P233/pen/Kzbsi/

Answer (score 0):

### May be this can help.

```
.tree {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.tree *,
.tree *::after,
.tree *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.tree ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}

.tree ul:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: .5em;
  width: 1em;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.tree > ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.tree li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  position: relative;
  padding: .5em 1em .5em 3em;
}

.tree li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 1.5em;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.tree li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 1.5em;
  width: 1em;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.tree li:first-child:before {
  top: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.tree li:last-child:before {
  bottom: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.tree li:only-child:before {
  display: none;
}

.tree > li {
  padding: 0;
}

.tree > li:before, .tree > li:after {
  display: none;
}

.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
    background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}

.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul::after,
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::after
{
    border-color:  #94a0b4;
}
```

Comment: from https://github.com/leejordan/flow/tree/master/

Comment: You should provide more explanation with an answer